# Is there any danger in using kill -11 instead of kill -9?

Tags: process, kill, process-management, segmentation-fault

I've realised recently that the `kill` utility can send any signal I want, so when I need to `SIGKILL` a process (when it's hanging or something), I send a `SIGSEGV` instead for a bit of a laugh (`kill -11` instead of `kill -9`.)

However, I don't know if this is bad practice. So, is `kill -11` more dangerous than `kill -9`? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `SIGSEGV` signal is sent by the kernel to a process that has made an invalid virtual memory reference (segmentation fault).

One way sending a `SIGSEGV` could be more "dangerous" is if you kill a process from a filesystem that is low on space. The default action when a process receives a `SIGSEGV` is to dump core to a file then terminate. The core file could be quite large, depending on the process, and could fill up the filesystem.

As @Janka has already mentioned, you can write code to tell your program how you want it to handle a `SIGSEGV` signal. You can't trap a `SIGKILL` or a `SIGSTOP`. I would suggest using a `SIGKILL` or a `SIGSTOP` when you only want to terminate a process. Using a `SIGSEGV` usually won't have bad repercussions, but it's possible the process you want to terminate could handle a `SIGSEGV` in a way you don't expect.

Answer (score 2):

SIGSEGV can be trapped by the receiving program and then, may do anything the program wants.

SIGKILL and SIGSTOP are the only signals a program cannot trap or ignore.